# Liquibase: how to run always a changeset as the last update operation

Tags: liquibase

I'm using [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org) on my project and need always to execute a procedure after each Liquibase updates...

Currently, the *changeSet* looks like this:

```
<changeSet id="liquibase-0" author="liquibase" runAlways="true">
   <sqlFile relativeToChangelogFile="true" path="procedure/owner-changer.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```

How can I do ensure that this *changeSet* will be run as the last update operation?

Thks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do this by splitting the changeset into two files: one that contains your "regular" changesets and the other only this single changeset. Then create a new "master" changeset that includes both, in the correct order:

```
<databaseChangeLog>

  <include file="standard_changes.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
  <include file="change_owner.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

`change_owner.xml` only contains that single changeset you have shown in your question.

This does not *guarantee* that it's always run last, because you could still run both change set manually in a different order, but if you always run `master.xml` then you can be sure that the "change owner" is executed last.

Theoretically you could give the "master" changelog the same name as your current file. But as the filename is part of the "signature" of changeset, I wouldn't do that if you have already deployed changes through the existing file.

Comment: it's a solution that I thought but, as you've said, there no guarantee that will be run last...

Comment: @gudepier That's the closest you can get to automate this. After all you can't prevent anyone from running the SQL script manually anyway. But using the include mechanism you can at least ensure that your standard deployment process does everything in the right order

Answer (score 11):

Since Liquibase 3.5.0 there's new `runOrder` attribute available with two possible values: `first` and `last`. Example for running changeSet as last one:

```
<changeSet id="123" author="author0" runAlways="true" runOrder="last">
    <sql> ... </sql>
</changeSet>
```

It isn't yet described in the documentation. Release notes: http://www.liquibase.org/2016/04/liquibase-3-5-0-released.html